# How to extract and cast individual dynamodb element from Amazon AWS using Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb, raspberry-pi3

I'm saving temperature data from Raspberry PI to Amazon DynamoDB over MQTT protocol. This is the layout of my database:

[image: screenshot 1]

I managed to set lambda function to read and send back each new db entry as a JSON message back to mqtt. So it can be read by the user:

[image: screenshot 2]

What I want to achieve is to extract only temperature value at arrival. Cast to integer type and simple check if temperature is lower or higher than threshold and based on that check send message on or off to mqtt. Then mqtt specific topic will read message (on or off) and will either turn on or off the led (heater simulator)

So what im asking for is to help in extracting temperature field from dynamodb. I should be with rest I hope...

thanks guys!

```
import boto3
import json

client = boto3.client('iot-data', region_name='eu-west-1')
dynamo = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamo.Table('mqtt_table')


# Change topic, qos and payload
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = table.scan()
    body = json.dumps(response['Items'])
    response = client.publish(
        topic='mytopic/iot2',
        qos=1,
        payload=body

    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to obtain the value of `temperature` field only, try the following:

```
for item in response['Items']:
    temperature = float(item['temperature'])
```

This should store the value of temperature in float in the variable.

--- Update 03/05/2018 ---

If you want to read an item as soon as it is added to the DynamoDB table, create a DynamoDB trigger. The documentation can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.Tutorial.html). Your lambda function code should look like below:

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print json.dumps(event, default=str)
    for record in event['Records']:
        temperature = record['dynamodb']['NewImage']['temperature']['S']
        # temperature variable contains the value of temperature of the item added to the DynamoDB table.
        print temperature
    # If you need to do something else, please do it here...
    return 'Completed'
```

Comment: Thanks that partially fixed my issue. I'm able to extract temperature value from db, but unfotunately this is the highest value not the latest in terms of time. Maybe I should change table.scan() to table.get_item()?

Comment: The above lines of code, loops through the response and assigns the current value in the loop to the `temperature` variable. If you want to get the latest value, you need to parse the payload and identify the temperature. Also, scan returns  maximum of 1 MB of data. If you need the complete data, you need to scan again till you get everything.

Comment: What would be the most simple and efficient way of implementation?

Comment: You need to send a key along with get_item(). The best way to implement this would be to read all the items and process them one-by-one to find out the highest value.

Comment: Hi Krishna. I tried already different combinations with no luck so far. I am only after starting coding in AWS and its not straightforward. If no luck soon I was thinking about parsing JSON object on raspberry side?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Find the highest value of temperature in the table?

Comment: Raspberry sends temperatures from sensor every 60 seconds to dynamo. I want lambda to read the latest temperature from database. Then check if temperature is higher or lower than eg 25 degrees send a string to mqtt topic like "on" or "off" based on this raspberry pi will turn on or off a led

Comment: Got it. Have you looked at DynamoDB triggers? Whenever a new item is added to the table, the DynamoDB trigger will be invoked. This will invoke a Lambda function and send the item as an input to it. You can do the processing based on that. Refer this link for more details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.Tutorial.html

Comment: I have the triggers configured just don't know how to extract  the temperature value from dynamo

Comment: Will study documentation provided and update you. Thanks for all the help so far!

Comment: I have updated my answer with the code change and link for the documentation.

Comment: Stream is enabled. Tried to use code from your answer but it's complaining about line with for loop? Am I missing table get item line?

Comment: "errorType": "KeyError",
  "errorMessage": "'Records'"

Comment: What does the first line print: `print json.dumps(event, default=str)`? Can you share the output.

Comment: For this I am using lambda console on AWS and that line does print nothing. Shall I use AWS CLI for this?

Comment: START RequestId: da27f3bd-2241-11e8-9811-ad9a6960ccf4 Version: $LATEST
'Records': KeyError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 11, in lambda_handler
    for record in event['Records']:
KeyError: 'Records'

END RequestId: da27f3bd-2241-11e8-9811-ad9a6960ccf4
REPORT RequestId: da27f3bd-2241-11e8-9811-ad9a6960ccf4 Duration: 14.88 ms Billed Duration: 100 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 32 MB

Comment: 20:01:47
END RequestId: 5dc7535d-2242-11e8-9d43-9b525fed374b
END RequestId: 5dc7535d-2242-11e8-9d43-9b525fed374b

20:01:47
REPORT RequestId: 5dc7535d-2242-11e8-9d43-9b525fed374b Duration: 1.06 ms Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 32 MB
REPORT RequestId: 5dc7535d-2242-11e8-9d43-9b525fed374b Duration: 1.06 ms Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 32 MB

Comment: {
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      11,
      "lambda_handler",
      "for record in event['Records']:"
    ]
  ],
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "errorMessage": "'Records'"
}
START RequestId: da6f67c5-2242-11e8-81e8-67428561d731 Version: $LATEST
'Records': KeyError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 11, in lambda_handler
    for record in event['Records']:
KeyError: 'Records'

END RequestId: da6f67c5-2242-11e8-81e8-67428561d731
REPORT RequestId: da6f67c5-2242-11e8-81e8-67428561d73

Comment: Are you running the lambda function manually? If so, that's wrong. You should add a new item to the DynamoDB and this lambda function will be executed.

Comment: This is what I am getting back to the topic. Same as before. I don't know why. This is very frustrating and as a temporary solution I may parse this on the raspberry and move on to something else 
{"Date": "2018-03-07 20:19:50.639789", "Device": "000001", "Temperature": "20.875", "Loop": "8"}